# ¿Cómo omito resultados de consulta dependiendo del dato de dos columnas en una BD MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, web

En una base de datos MySQL, tengo una tabla que contiene muchos datos de muchos autos. Tengo la columna **clase**, que alberga datos como 'Sedán', '4x4', 'Sport', 'Racing' o 'SUV'; otra columna es **combustible**, que contiene 'Diesel', 'Gas natural' o 'Eléctrico'.

Lo que necesito es formular la consulta de forma que muestre todos los autos pero que OMITA los que tienen por **combustible** 'Gas natural' pero SOLO SI en **clase** contienen el dato 'Sedán'.

Lo que he intentado es:

```
SELECT * FROM autos WHERE (clase = 'Sedán' AND combustible = 'Gas natural');
```

Pero esa consulta no devuelve el resto de clases de autos :(

También...

```
SELECT * FROM autos WHERE (combustible = 'Gas natural' OR clase = 'Sedán');
```

Usando AND u OR, e invirtiendo las condiciones, no funciona como quiero. Estoy inquieta porque no hallo el modo de hacerla funcionar.

Gracias por sus respuestas chicos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está es la consulta que necesitas:

```
SELECT * FROM autos WHERE NOT (clase = 'Sedán' AND combustible = 'Gas natural');
```

Utilice el operador `NOT` para seleccionar lo que no corresponda.

Comment: Muchas gracias César. Efectivamente, esa es la consulta :D

Answer (score 0):

Con esta query me va perfecto a mí en otra BBDD, así que tiene que funcionarte. Mucho ojo a los espacios, mayúsculas y tildes en el campo.

```
SELECT * FROM autos WHERE combustible != 'Gas natural' AND clase != 'Sedán';
```

Si quieres no confundirte con eso puedes usar el operador NOT LIKE en la condición y poner algo así como:

```
SELECT * FROM autos WHERE combustible NOT LIKE '%Gas%' AND clase NOT LIKE '%Sed%';
```

Así todas las palabras que contengan Sed de Sedán y Gas de Gas Natural no deberán ser especificadas. Así evitas problemas con tildes, espacios o incluso haber escrito "natral" en vez de "Natural".

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto

```
SELECT * FROM autos WHERE (clase != 'Sedán' AND combustible != 'Gas natural');
```

En base a los comentarios sobre que filtre todos los que usen gas natural con excepcion de los autos clase sedan una alternativa seria

```
SELECT * FROM auto WHERE combustible != 'Gas natural' OR clase = 'Sedan';
```

Comment: Hola! No me funciona así... Omite todos los autos de esa clase, y todos los que funcionan a gas natural. :'(

Comment: Revisa tu pregunta  asi la formulaste "'Lo que necesito es formular la consulta de forma que muestre todos los autos pero que OMITA los que tienen por combustible 'Gas natural' y que en clase contengan el dato 'Sedán'."

Comment: Crack81, ya corregí... necesito muestre todo excepto los que tienen por combustible 'Gas natural', SOLO SI en clase contienen 'Sedán' ;)